# Jenkins build with maven-release-plugin fails

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Did anybody faced the following exception during jenkins build (Java 8, IBM sdk) with the maven-release-plugin:

```
[INFO] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0-internal). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
[INFO] java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO]  at javax.lang.model.util.ElementScanner6.scan(ElementScanner6.java:142)
[INFO]  at javax.lang.model.util.ElementScanner6.visitType(ElementScanner6.java:189)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ComputeAnnotationSet.visitType(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:777)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ComputeAnnotationSet.visitType(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:758)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.accept(Symbol.java:1162)
[INFO]  at javax.lang.model.util.ElementScanner6.scan(ElementScanner6.java:157)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ComputeAnnotationSet.scan(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:798)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.findAnnotationsPresent(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:993)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:891)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1182)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1182)
```

Further exception information:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli) on project [myProject]: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
```

Without the maven-release-plugin the build is successful. The plugin configuration looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <tagBase>[myTagUrl]</tagBase>
        <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
        <branchBase>[myBranchUrl]</branchBase>
        <checkModificationExcludes>
            <checkModificationExclude>src/main/java/META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode</checkModificationExclude>
        </checkModificationExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Java version information:

`java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6480sr1-20150417_01(SR1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 AIX ppc64-64 Compressed References 20150410_243669 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_Java8_SR1_20150410_1531_B243669
JIT  - tr.r14.java_20150402_88976.03
GC   - R28_Java8_SR1_20150410_1531_B243669_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20150410_243669)
JCL - 20150413_01 based on Oracle jdk8u45-b13`

Solution:
Obviously the maven-release-plugin and the apt-maven-plugin have a resource access problem (maybe due to threads created by the release-plugin).
Therefore waiting a few seconds before the apt-maven-plugin get called solved this issue.

Comment: Which Java 1.8 version exactly do you use?

Comment: I added the java version information

Comment: Are you using SVN, Git etc. to release? Cause what's looking weired is ` Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'`

Comment: We are using SVN, the scm tag is available, also the distributionManagement url

Comment: Are you running on Jenkins or local? Is SVN available via Path ?

Comment: The build is running on jenkins and SVN is available via the configured path

Comment: Are you running jenkins on Java 8 furthermore is your job a Maven Job Type or a freestyle Job?

Comment: No jenkins is running with Java 1.7.0_80 and the job is a "Free style" job. On my local machine the release build is successful. The curious thing is that the release build on jenkins for other jobs is successful (also freestyle jobs and with the same SVN parent path).

Comment: Are you using some kind of toolchain configuration?

Comment: If you mean the maven-toolchains-plugin, no this is not configured in our projects.

Comment: I solved the problem, look at the updated question